# How to upload images or static files in a django project

Tags: html, css, django

Ive tried everything. I cannot upload images in my website. How to do that. It just gives an icon of an image not the image itself. When i write {% load static %} in my html5 file which is running bootstrap css stuff it simply displays that on the webpage. it takes this command as text. Also ive tried to shift the whole iconic folder i downloaded to static directory but py manage.py collectstatic showed 0 files  , 130 unmodified.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

static folder should be inside project with manage.py file as shown in the image below.
[image]

and add this in setting

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

You have created multiple static folder and for what I think django only allows single static folder and wrap everything inside it.